# Creating a void method that reads a file, that can be called by other methods in the class?

Tags: java, file, io, void

```
public class Dash {
    public void readFile(String fil) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(fil));
            String text = input.next();
            input.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
    }

    public int getNumDashes() throws FileNotFoundException {
        readFile(fil);
        String text = input.next();
        // code to find number of dashes from the string of the read file.
    }
}
```

As indicated in the title, I would like to read the file in one method. Since I cannot return a string from `readFile` method, I would have to obtain the string from within the `getNumDashes` method. However, I'm not sure how to do this. I would like my second method's return value to be based of off whatever file name is passed into `readFile()`.

Comment: Any particular reason you cannot return a string from readFile()? Or you are not sure how to do that?

Comment: Yes I aggree with @YibinLin. Use return for readFile then you can have the control of if file reading is successfull or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a non-static field for your string, where you store your text from the input file.

```
public class Dash {
    String text;
    public void readFile(String fil) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try{
            Scanner input = new Scanner (new File(fil));
            text= input.next();
            input.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        }

    public int getNumDashes() throws FileNotFoundException {
        readFile(fil);
        // You can read from the field *text* here and process the input
        // code to find number of dashes from the string of the read file.
    }
}
```